# deleting javascript element when form reset button pressed

Tags: javascript

In javascript, i have a element div that pops up when there is a error in the HTML form. The problem is the element does not go away upon pressing the reset button in the HTML form. i would like it to disappear when the reset button is pressed, and appear only when there is an error in the form i.e no field inputs.
the HTML form:

```
<form id="contact" action="" onsubmit="checkContactForm( this ); return false;">
  <p>Fill in the form below to send me a message!</p>    
  <p>
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input name="firstname" id="firstname" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input name="lastname" id="lastname" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="resetField( this );"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

The Javascript :

```
function checkContactForm( theForm ) {
  for ( i in requiredFields ) {
       var fieldName = requiredFields[ i ];
       var theField = theForm[ fieldName ];
      if ( !theField.value || theField.value == "Error" ) {
        theField.style.color = "#f66";
        theField.value = "Error";
        var emptyFields = true;
      }

      if (!emptyFields) {
        theForm.submit();
      }
      else
      {
        var div = document.createElement ("div");
        div.id = "div";
        div.style.width = "400px";
        div.style.height = "20px";
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.marginTop = "-550px";
        div.style.marginLeft = "160px";
        div.style.fontStyle = "italic";
        div.style.padding = "10px 20px 10px 10px";
        div.style.background = "#D4D4D4";
        div.style.borderStyle = "Solid";
        div.style.borderColor = "#ff6666";
        div.style.boxShadow = "0px 2px 10px 0px";
        div.innerHTML = "Please fill in all fields before submitting the form";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        /*$(div).fadeOut(5000);*/
      }

      if (  ) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild ("div");
      }
    }
  }

  function resetField( theField ) {
    if ( theField.value == "Error" || theField.value =="" ) {
    theField.value = "";
    theField.style.color = "#000";
  }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with your code. What's the line `if (  )`?

Comment: wow, where to start... so you are only declaring ```emptyFields = true``` in side an if block. What is its default state? ```if( )``` is also not a thing

Comment: sorry that was in there temproarily i was messing around with stuff to get it to work. i've taken that out. i was thinking parentNode.removeChild

Answer (score 0):

Alternative - instead of creating the DIV via javascript using document.createElement(), I recommend just putting the HTML for the DIV into the page with style="display:none;" to hide it initially.  Give the div an id such as id="errorDiv".  When wanting to show the error message, use:

```
document.getElementById('errorDiv').style.display = 'block';
```

When ready to hide the message, use:

```
document.getElementById('errorDiv').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
OR 
document.getElementsByClassName("my-elements").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function removeDummy() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('firstname');
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp